# 2 subplots sharing y-axis (no space between) with single color bar

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

Does anyone have a matplotlib example of two plots sharing the y-axis (with no space between the plots) with a single color bar pertaining to both subplots?  I have not been able to find examples of this yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created the following code based on your question. Personally I do not like it to have no space between the subplots at all. If you do want to change this at some point all you need to do is to replace `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = -.059)` with `plt.tight_layout()`.

Hope this helps

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

#Random data
data = numpy.random.random((10, 10))

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, aspect = "equal")
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, aspect = "equal", sharey = ax1)  #Share y-axes with subplot 1

#Set y-ticks of subplot 2 invisible
plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)

#Plot data
im1 = ax1.pcolormesh(data)
im2 = ax2.pcolormesh(data)

#Define locations of colorbars for both subplot 1 and 2
divider1 = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax1 = divider1.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

divider2 = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax2 = divider2.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

#Create and remove the colorbar for the first subplot
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(im1, cax = cax1)
fig.delaxes(fig.axes[2])

#Create second colorbar
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(im2, cax = cax2)

#Adjust the widths between the subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = -.059)

plt.show()
```

The result is the following:

[image]

Comment: What if `fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, aspect = "equal")
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, aspect = "equal", sharey = ax1)` results in `AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute '_adjustable'`?

Comment: @durbachit, If I copy paste the lines you provide I am not able to reproduce your error. I am guessing that your error has a different origin. I suggest you try to run the three lines of code you posted in your comment. If you are able to produce the error with these three lines I suggest to have a look at the version of matplotlib. The one I am using is: 1.5.1.